# Execute Asyntask from timer

Tags: android, timer

I using pushy notification in my driver android app.So my problem is that when app get notification(passenger detail),I want to execute Asyntask from Braodcast receiver after 30 seconds. I have used code given below -

```
final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
                .newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                String cancel = preferences.getString("cancel_status", "1");
                Log.d("cancell", "cancell");
                if (cancel != "1")
                    new ConfirmRejectService(context).execute(message, "2");
            }
        }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: my problem is that asyntask is not executing

Comment: Are your sure the first line has been executed and runnable not?

Comment: If i toast in run method its ok  but asyntask is not called

Comment: after searching i found that asyntask can be called from main thread only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try handler to solve your problem. It have worked for me.`

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{}